# Drupal service session handling

Tags: 7, services

In my angular app, I am trying to use headless Drupal using service module. I can't able to find a proper documentation to handle session authentication for each subsequent calls. My each request ends in "csrf validation failed" message.

Can anyone suggest a good tutorial or steps to handle session authentication?

Answer (score 0):

For any POST, PATCH or DELETE request, you always need to pass along the `X-CSRF-Token`.

After logging in via REST, the new `X-CSRF-Token` should be provided in that data result, then you can just set that aside (in a global variable, in local storage, etc) and then pass it along with each request.

I personally use (and created) this module to make things easier: https://www.drupal.org/project/angular_drupal